# Composite WPF EventAggregator subscriptions being lost

Tags: wpf, events, eventaggregator, cal

In my Composite WPF application I have an event that is published when the user double-clicks on a control. Modules subscribe to the event and perform an action when necessary.

This event seems to stop working at random. Sometimes when I run the application I can trigger the event with no problems, other times I can only trigger it a few times before the modules stop receiving the event.

When I look in the debugger the CAL `EventAggregator` still has the event, but the event has no subscriptions. How can `EventAggregator` be losing subscriptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was the garbage collector removing the subscriptions. I'll have to read up on the internals, but when I replaced

```
this.mEventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe(SomeFunction);
```

with

```
this.mEventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe(
    SomeFunction, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
```

it started working. The UI thread parameters wasn't my problem, but for others it may be important to ensure you're handling the event on the right thread too.

Comment: The EventAggregator uses weak references (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx) unless you explicitly tell it not to.