# PRISM 5, EventAggregator losing subscription

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

I'm trying to use the eventaggregator (Unity container) to fire/publish an event when my shell is closing
so I can save some settings in a View. The problem is when I exit the application there is no longer any subscribers to the event, it's as if something is clearing them out. I'm new to event aggregation so apologies if this is something obvious!

I've done this in my Shell:

```
    public Shell(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        var theevent =_eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShellClosingEvent>();
        theevent.Publish("closing");

    }
```

And my View:(I subscribe in the constructor)

```
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShellClosingEvent>().Subscribe((x) =>
        {
            if (x != "closing") return;
            using (var fs = new FileStream("clientGridSettings.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                ClientsGrid.SaveCustomizations(fs);
            }

        });
```

The event:

```
public class ShellClosingEvent : PubSubEvent<string>
{
}
```

Comment: Did you try SubscriptionToken Subscribe(Action<TPayload> action, bool keepSubscriberReferenceAlive)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prism Event Aggregation - subscriber not triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810730/prism-event-aggregation-subscriber-not-triggered) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132690/composite-wpf-eventaggregator-subscriptions-being-lost/1132775#1132775 ?

Comment: Hi, I tried   eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShellClosingEvent>().Subscribe(OnClosing, true); But the event aggregator still has no subscribers when my Shell OnClosing is fired :(